# Maven artifact jboss-as-client broken (trove:trove:jar:2.1.1)

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have serious problems on a new computer setting up my existing maven project. Eclipse complains dozens of times about missing artifacts:

```
Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.5:compile
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.5:compile
Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
...
```

While downloading the files for the local repository I encounter the following message (executing `mvn compile`:

```
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/trove/trove/2.1.1/trove-2.1.1.pom
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/trove/trove/2.1.1/trove-2.1.1.pom
....
[ERROR] ... Failed to read artifact descriptor for trove:trove:jar:2.1.1:
        Could not transfer artifact trove:trove:pom:2.1.1 from/to jboss 
        (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2): Access denied to:
        http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/trove/trove/2.1.1/trove-2.1.1.pom
```

I've followed the instructions http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenSettings and use the public repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
   <name>JBoss Repository</name>
   <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>>
</repository>
```

The responsible dependency in my project is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It seems the problem is related to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682, but since it's unlikely the repository URL will be fixed, I'm looking for a workaround! I don't encounter this problem on other machines, but it occurs if the maven repository is deleted and will be rebuild.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I had that issue once before and afaik know "Using Deprecated Dependencies" helped me.

Have a look at http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users on paragraph "Using Deprecated Dependencies". Sorry I might be wrong, but it might be worth a shot... :)

Maven Source Quote:

```
  <repositories>
    <!-- other repos here -->
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-deprecated-repository</id>
      <name>JBoss Deprecated Maven Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```