# Remote EJB call jboss 6 dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb, jboss6.x

I have a webapp (jsf + hibernate) deployed on a tomcat 6 server and i went to communicate remotely with some ejb deployed in a jboss application server 6.1.0.Final.

Does any one know all maven dependencies i have to add to make that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this jaikiran pai post](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenArtifactIdForJBossAS6ClientJar),  the dependency would be:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>  
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>  
    <version>6.0.0.Final</version>  
    <type>pom</type>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: You can also use the dependency `<version>6.1.0.Final</version>` which corresponding to version of JBoss AS 6.1.0 Final, note that you have to enable repository for **"Using Deprecated Dependencies"**. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556858/maven-artifact-jboss-as-client-broken-trovetrovejar2-1-1

Comment: You are right Federico, version should be 6.1.0.Final.. I missed that detail.. Thank you for correction